# Using public enums to control TimeZone in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, enums, timezone

I've been updating some code to Swift 3.0. I was using Melvin Rivera's fantastic [date extension for Swift 3.0](https://github.com/melvitax/DateHelper). Now Melvin declares TimeZone as a public enum as follows:

```
public enum TimeZone {
case local, utc
}
```

Now I have trouble with my pre Swift 3.0 code that used some common TimeZone code. For Example:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
    df.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a"
    df.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: usersTimeZone)
```

Whenever I use such code I get a compiler error stating, "'TimeZone' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers". What is the correct way to use the various TimeZone functions if TimeZone has been constructed as a public enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says that `TimeZone` does not have any accessible initializers and it´s because it does not have any. TimeZone is an enum, you can type `TimeZone.local` or `TimeZone.utc` as it works today.

And for the initializers part you can read more about init [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) at Apples documentation site.

You can read more about enums on [Apples documentation site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html).

**Edit:**

Update your code to the following:

```
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "MMM d, yyyy, hh:mm a"
df.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: String(describing: Zone.local))

public enum Zone: String {
    case local
    case utc
}
```

1. I renamed the TimeZone enum to Zone beacuase TimeZone is a
   reserved workd for the DateFormatter
2. You need to pass a String value for TimeZone and that is what
3. I have updated the code to Swift 3.0 syntax

.

Comment: Thanks Rashwan, I tried to change my code to df.timeZone = TimeZone.local but I get a compiler error stating, "Cannot assign value of type 'TimeZone' to type 'TimeZone!'". I'm still a bit confused as to what code I should use to replace my pre swift 3.0 code.

Comment: @Tom, I fixed your errors. Use my code and it will work with Swift 3.0.